# How to create an activity with its corresponding XML file just tapping a button

Tags: android, xml, button, android-activity

I'm programming an app which one of its functionalities is that the users can tap on a plus button (typical (+)...) that has to create a new activity and a new XML file with a specific structure.

I'm beginner on Android and also in Stack Overflow, so due to that I'm unable to post images and make this question easier to understand.

I need you to summarize how to program this. I'm not telling you to codify my code, I just need to know if it's possible to do and ,more or less, the steps to get it.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by create? create the xml or do you mean "start" a new  activity? Give us a code example and we can help more.

Comment: I agree with @Blundell , your question is ambigous. However, both of those cases are possible. You can change the layout of the current activity as well as launch a new activity and set its layout according to a custom .xml file

Comment: I mean to start a new one from zero. Tapping on the button should create an activity structurally identical to the activity that has the plus button. It's like having a vector of activities that you can add or remove but all of them has the same principal structure. Sorry but I can't give you a code example.

Comment: Sure that is simple enough to do, but I'd discourage you from doing it, since it has no practical application.

Comment: Sorry, I know that it's not a normal question and can be difficult to understand. I just need a guide to work. Obviously it has a practical application but I can't show you its functionality due to I can't post neither images nor photos of my intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the activity yourself and have a button open the activity.

You'd start by making a new android activity. With eclipse it's simply File >> New >> Other >> Android Activity and then just fill out the form and hit finish. Make sure your current project is open.

Draw the button in your xml file, make sure it has a unique Id to reference and your text is declared in your strings.xml file that should look like this.

```
<string name="strX">(x)</string>
```

then in your activity's xml file under your button make sure you have

```
android:text="@string/strX"
```

You can also reference this in the GUI in the properties window under text.

With the button code in your .java you could use OnClickListener and Intent and the code for the button would look something like this.

```
TextView buttonYourButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ButtonYourButtonId);
Button pushYourButton = (Button) buttonPlay;

pushYourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent nameOfIntent = new Intent(NameOfCurrentClass.this, NameOfNewClass.class);
    startActivity(nameOfIntent);    
  }
});
```

`R.id.ButtonYourButton` is the Id you gave the button, and the `.class` is the name of the public class in that .java file. Like:

```
public class MainActivity { ...
```

Anyways, good luck I was where you were about a month ago. Don't forget to check out tutorials on Android development on youtube, there are about a million of them. Also you can search stackoverflow for questions that already have been asked.

Comment: Thank you "Unknown"! jeje it sound to be what I need. Yes, I'm watching tutorials and also reading in books but it was impossible for me to found this question anywhere.

Comment: Sorry Joey, when I was writing you I couldn't see your name(it was User23242...), so that I called you Unknown haha.. Sorry man!

Comment: No worries José, it was my first question I answered and my name hadn't updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is how you'd do it, if you're **sure you want to create a new instance of the activity from that very same activity**. First, make a reference to your "plus button". Assuming the `android:id="@+id/plusButton`, it'd be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Initialize your layout and variables
        findViewById(R.id.plusButton).setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

This would launch a new instance of the same Activity (MainActivity) and give it focus.

Comment: Thank you Nitro. This question is as useful as the first one I received. If I could give you repu I'll do but my repu is so insignificant even for this...

Comment: No worries, hopefully you will find the application, although I'm afraid it'd be an exploitable feature of your application that can cause memory overload for the user.

Comment: Yes Nitro, I have it in mind. The information in the activities will be only text and it has a limit of 15 activities.